# Read value in XML Node - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

This is my code.......

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SET @XML = CAST('<Session id="ID969138672" realTimeID="4300815712">

  <VarValues>
    <varValue id="ID123" source="Internal" name="DisconnectedBy">VisitorClosedWindow</varValue>
    <varValue id="ID1234" source="PreChat"  name="email">1234@mail.ru</varValue>
  </VarValues>

</Session>
' AS XML)

SELECT 
 xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)')
,xmlData.Col.value('@source','varchar(max)')
,xmlData.Col.value('@name','varchar(max)')
FROM @XML.nodes('//Session/VarValues/varValue') xmlData(Col);
```

This is the output.....

[image]

How can I include the actual values of the varValue?

I need to read the values **VisistorClosedWindow** and **1234@mail.ru** values as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get that by doing this:

```
xmlData.Col.value('.','varchar(max)')
```

So the select would be:

```
SELECT 
 xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)')
,xmlData.Col.value('@source','varchar(max)')
,xmlData.Col.value('@name','varchar(max)')
,xmlData.Col.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @XML.nodes('//Session/VarValues/varValue') xmlData(Col);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `.value('.', 'varchar(50)`) line for that:

```
SELECT 
     xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(25)'),
     xmlData.Col.value('@source','varchar(50)'),
     xmlData.Col.value('@name','varchar(50)'),
     xmlData.Col.value('.','varchar(50)')         -- <== this gets your the element's value
FROM @XML.nodes('//Session/VarValues/varValue') xmlData(Col);
```